# NodeJS: Properties disappearing from response?

Tags: node.js, async-await, loopbackjs

In my console:

```
[ CampaignStrategy {
    id: 248,
    id_mm: 828419,
    strategy_name: "Norhart_Encore_AUD",
    impressions: 7623,
    clicks: 13,
    TEST_PROPERTY: '222222',
    ordered_impressions:
     Orderedimpression { ordered_impressions: '123', id: 7, strategy_id: 248 }
    },
  ...
]
```

Response object received in the browser (XHR):

```
[
  {
    "id": 248,
    "id_mm": 828419,
    "strategy_name": "Norhart_Encore_AUD",
    "impressions": 7623,
    "clicks": 13,
},
...
]
```

Notice how `TEST_PROPERTY` and `ordered_impressions` don't exist in the latter. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my controller logic:

```
@get('/campaignStrategies/{id}')
  async findStrategies(
    @param.path.number('id') id: number,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const campaignStrats = await this.campaignStrategyRepository.find({
      where: {
        campaignId: id
      }
    });

    const campaignStratsIds = campaignStrats.map(strat => {
      return { strategy_id: strat.id }
    });

    const campaignSettings = await this.orderedimpressionRepository.find({
      where: {
        or: campaignStratsIds
      }
    });

    const settingsTable = await campaignSettings.reduce((acc: any, setting: any) => {
      acc[setting.strategy_id] = setting;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    const fullData = campaignStrats.map((strat: any) => {
      strat['TEST_PROPERTY'] = '222222'
      strat['ordered_impressions'] = settingsTable[`${strat.id}`];
      return strat;
    });

    console.log(fullData);

    return fullData;
  }
```

Comment: Received where? You need to show how you send and receive the data.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I updated my post, it's an XHR from the browser

Comment: Are you sure you ain't have caching issues?

Comment: @StPaulis Tried clearing site data and also using the hard reload option. Nothing changed.

Comment: Incognito? Restart :P? It seems weird.

Comment: @StPaulis I did try incognito already and restarted the server countless times. I've wasted hours on this bug and still can't figure out what am I missing.

Comment: ```
@get('/campaignStrategies/{id}')
  async findStrategies(
    @param.path.number('id') id: number,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const campaignStrats = await this.campaignStrategyRepository.find({
      where: {
        campaignId: id
      }
    });

    const fullData = campaignStrats.map((strat: any) => {
      return {...strat,  TEST_PROPERTY: 2222 }
    });

    console.log(fullData);

    return fullData;
  }
```

 Is this working?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to send code if is not in answer

Comment: @StPaulis It did it! Thanks, really.
Can you post your solution as an answer and explain why this worked and why what I was doing didn't?
Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
const fullData = campaignStrats
    .map((strat: any) => { 
        return {...strat, TEST_PROPERTY: 2222 /* and so on /* } 
    }
```

With that way you return a different object than the one you have on `campaignStrats` list.

PS: I am not sure, why `console.log` is showing us the wrong response thought, maybe someone would comment or edit here.